# Cant get HTTP Post result of Website

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Sorry for my bad english.

I am working on a Teamspeak plugin.

I am trying to get the website content, where I posted some Parameters.

The Website is http://ts3.cloud/ts3proxy and the Parameters which I found with a sniffer are "Input" and "port".

When I call http://ts3.cloud/ts3proxy?input=testserver.de&port=9987 the results not same as when I go to Website, type in Manual and use the Buttom.

Can someone say why it is like this? What should I do that I get the right result?

Xploid.

Comment: How are you doing it manually?  What does your equivalent code look like?  Give us the 2 specific things to compare against, and the 2 different results you're seeing (and which one you're expecting to see)

Comment: With manually I me that I enter the values on the page and not on the URL. I havent a Code yet, because the way is not working.
Little example: when I go to this site, type in the serverip and press Generate Proxadress, then it generates a proxy-serverip.
When I enter the URL with the required Parameters (http://ts3.cloud/ts3proxy.php?input=8.8.8.8&port=9987) then I will redirected to the main Page. 
So I am not abe to use the ParameterURL-Link which I Need for my plugin

Comment: _"When I call http://ts3.cloud/ts3proxy?input=testserver.de&port=9987"_ -- If I understand you correctly, you just try to enter this in the adress bar. In this case you are not doing a POST request, but a simple GET request. In a POST request, the parameters are *not* appended to the URL, but send as *data* to the server. You need to read up on the differences between POST and GET. There are tools online, that you can use to test a POST request.

Comment: Sorry I meant GET. but when I enter "ts3.cloud/ts3proxy?input=testserver.de&port=9987" theres not the same result like when I visit the page and enter the value "testserver.de". How can I use the Parameterurl to get the same result like I visit the site and enter the values?

Comment: When you enter something in that website form, it does a POST request (because `<form action="" method="post">`). When you enter an URL in the browser, it is always a GET request. How can you expect that both will give the same result? Read up on HTTP request methods and you can answer the question by yourself. For starters: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)

Comment: I read it and understand now the difference. But what should I do to give the page parameters through the URL, to get the same result like when I enter the values on page?